# Sklearn MinMaxScaler deprecation error for y

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler to scale the y values for an RNN built with Keras

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#snip
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
(11025, 21)
(11025,)
```

but

```
minmax_scaler = MinMaxScaler(copy=False)
minmax_scaler.fit(X_train, y_train)

minmax_scaler.transform(X_train)
minmax_scaler.transform(y_train)
```

Throws an error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:359: DeprecationWarning: 
Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. 
Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
warnings.warn(DEPRECATION_MSG_1D, DeprecationWarning)
```

I've not succeeded with either of the "reshapes()" suggested in the error.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1549 looked promising but was suddenly closed.

How should/can I scale y so that it remains consistent with X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the technical aspect of what you're trying to do, and there's the fundamental one.

Technically, note that these shapes,

```
(11025, 21)
(11025,)
```

are different: the first is 2d, the second is 1d. The `transform` method expects a 2d shape. If you *really* want to pass the `y` to it, you can do something like

```
minmax_scaler.transform(y_train.reshape((len(y_train), 1)))
```

which will make it a 2d array.

Now this won't throw, but, fundamentally, this is almost surely not what you want. Your transformer was trained for `X`, not `y`. You should either train a transformer on `y` (see below) before transforming, or consider whether you really want to transform `y`.

**Edit**

If you really want to transform the `y`, it should look like

```
some_scaler.fit(y_train.reshape((len(y_train), 1)), y).transform(y_train.reshape((len(y_train), 1)))
```

Comment: Transforming y isn't usual ?

Comment: @gregn Transforming `y` when the transformer was `fit` on something else (in the first parameter) is highly unusual. I'll update the answer - see if it's clearer.